# Trying to import nested types from class

Tags: java

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. My top-level classes are in unnamed packages (for now; I'm planning on setting up packages later).

Iclass1.java:

```
public class Iclass1 {    
    public static class Nested1 {
        // whatever
    }    
}
```

Iclass2.java:

```
import Iclass1.*;
public class Iclass2 {
    private Nested1 someMember;
    // etc.
}
```

After I compile `Iclass1.java` with no errors, the compiler complains when I compile `Iclass2.java`: "error: package Iclass1 does not exist".

But the JLS says:  (7.5.2)

```
import PackageOrTypeName . * ;
```

> The PackageOrTypeName must be the canonical name (§6.7) of a package,
>   a class type, an  interface type, an enum type, or an annotation type.

and:  (6.7)

> The fully qualified name of a top level class or top level interface that is declared in an unnamed package is the simple name of the class or interface.
>
> For every primitive type, named package, top level class, and top level interface, the canonical name is the same as the fully qualified name.

So it seems like Iclass1 is the canonical name of the type I'm trying to use in the `import`.  What am I doing wrong?

(P.S. I now think `import static` would have been better, but it doesn't work either.)

Comment: but - over all - which is the right answer?

Comment: Sajal's now-edited answer addresses the question properly. The other answers have been either wrong (the suggested solutions don't work) or unhelpful (they just say "don't do that") or both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have no packages, don't use import.

Because JLS [§7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) tells you not to:

> A type in an unnamed package (§7.4.2) has no canonical name, so the
>   requirement for a canonical name in every kind of import declaration
>   implies that (a) types in an unnamed package cannot be imported, and
>   (b) static members of types in an unnamed package cannot be imported.
>   As such, §7.5.1, §7.5.2, §7.5.3, and §7.5.4 all require a compile-time
>   error on any attempt to import a type (or static member thereof) in an
>   unnamed package.

Comment: Hmmm... The passage you quote from the JLS is in italics, which seems to indicate that this isn't intended to be a "rule" but rather explanatory text that explains the consequences of the rules.  But it seems to contradict the rules in 6.7, which imply that a type in an unnamed package *does* have a canonical name, and doesn't add any rules that say this case is an exception.  Something seems to be missing.  In any event, thanks for pointing me to this "rule", since naturally it didn't look like a rule so I couldn't find it.

Comment: @ajb I think it was hard for them to explain it too. :) 6.7 starts with "...Every primitive type, named package, top level class, and top level interface has a fully qualified name:". Note "named package".

Comment: But aren't my classes here "top level classes"?

Comment: Yes, and that is why you are able to use directly.

Comment: That's not the point.  You wanted me to notice that 6.7 starts with a reference to a "named package", which would exclude unnamed packages.  But the same sentence also says "top level classes".  So they should have fully qualified names in their own right.  And later on 6.7 says that top level classes' canonical names are the same as their fully qualified names.  Since it's whether the *type* has a canonical name that matters, the fact that this sentence also mentions named packages shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: @ajb You should see the difference end of that 6.7 between fully qualified name and canonical name.

Comment: FYI, I've just gotten confirmation from the JLS editor that this is indeed an error in the JLS.  It looks like the plan is to redefine "fully-qualified name" and "canonical name" so that classes in unnamed packages don't have one.  They want to prohibit such imports because "implementations are allowed to have more than one unnamed package" (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6975015).

Comment: @ajb It's a good enhancement to keep 'importing' consistent! They did't apply that to v6 though.

Answer (score 2):

It's very inconsistent of java, but it appears that you can't import inner classes if the top level container class is in the default package.

If you put the two classes in any package, importing works fine.

Try creating a directory for those two classes called `foo`, moving them in there, then adding   `package foo;` as the first line in each file.

Comment: I don't think he's trying to solve the problem, I think he's trying to understand it.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to do an import so you can declare the private member in `Iclass2` as `private Nested1 someMember;`, without doing `Iclass1.Nested1` you must have `Iclass1` in a package.

Once you have it in a package, you can import the nested members like so:

```
import mypackage.Iclass1.Nested1;
import mypackage.Iclass1.*;
import static mypackage.Iclass1.Nested1;
import static mypackage.Iclass1.*;
```

You can't import anything from the default namespace/package.

Comment: The downvotes are because this answer is not correct. You simply cannot import from an unnamed package.